# email to check size / if it's complete

Tags: powershell

Running the following script:

```cs
$FileToCheck = Get-Item -Path $folder/test.zip -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$EmailSplat = @{
    To = 'business@email.com'
    CC = 'admin@email.com'
    #SmtpServer = 'smtp.server.net'
    From = 'my@email.com'
    Priority = 'High'
}
$folder = "C:\test\"
#  first condition: 'If the file does not exist, or was not created today, an e-mail should be sent that states "File not created" or similar.'

if ((-not $FileToCheck) -or ($FileToCheck.CreationTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-1))) {
    $EmailSplat.Subject = 'File not Found or not created today'
    $EmailSplat.building = 'This is the email building'
    Send-MailMessage @EmailSplat
    # second condition 'If the file exists and was created today, but has no content, no e-mail should be sent.'
} elseif (($FileToCheck) -and ($FileToCheck.Length -le 2)) {
    #third condition and the default condition if it does not match the other conditions
} else {
    $EmailSplat.Subject = 'Active Directory Accounts To Check'
    $EmailSplat.building = Get-Content -Path/test.zip    //maybe add the file??
    Send-MailMessage @EmailSplat
}
```

Goal: Check if file .zip is complete, once is complete it sends an email to let business that file is good to go. I'm running the script, getting no errors but no alert emails either.

Build on: Add maybe a time that the email could be sent. For example, script will run every morning, at 6:00 the email gets sent to users to notify that the file is complete.

Comment: Have you testet just the Send-MailMessage command?

Comment: Add `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` at the top of the script, so errors are shown. Use the `Attachments` parameter to add files (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage). `building` is not a valid parameter of Send-MailMessage

Comment: Thanks @mhu , i will look into it . Any reason why  im not getting any emails, without adding the file into the email

Comment: thanks for the $ErrorAction -  points it out to .building  : Get-Content : Illegal characters in path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The $Folder variable needs to be on the line before the "$FileToCheck = Get-Item..." line since it uses that variable.
2. There is no such parameter "building" in the Send-MailMessage cmdlet. I think you are after Body, since you are trying to Get-Content...? 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6
3. Another note is that Get-Content won't be able to read the contents of a zip file. You would need to unzip the file then read the file or add the file as an attachment.
   This is an example of using Get-Content on an zip file that has only a text file in it:
   PK
    ï¸ÌN_S³         test.txtsdafasdfPK 
    ï¸ÌN_S³                      test.txtPK      6   .

Answer (score 1):

Add $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" at the top of the script, so errors are shown.

Use the Attachments parameter to add files, `building` is not a valid parameter of Send-MailMessage

Get-Content is not needed, just add the path to the attachment:

```
$EmailSplat.Attachments = "Path/test.zip"
```

So something like this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

$folder = "C:\test"
$fileToCheck = Get-Item -Path (Join-Path $folder test.zip) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$emailOptions = @{
    "To"         = "business@email.com"
    "CC"         = "admin@email.com"
    "SmtpServer" = "smtp.server.net"
    "From"       = "my@email.com"
    "Priority"   = "High"
}

#  first condition: If the file does not exist, or was not created today, an e-mail should be sent that states "File not created" or similar.
if ((-not $fileToCheck) -or ($fileToCheck.CreationTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-1))) 
{
    $emailOptions.Subject = "File not Found or not created today"
    Send-MailMessage @emailOptions
} 
elseif ($fileToCheck -and ($fileToCheck.Length -le 2)) 
{
    # second condition: If the file exists and was created today, but has no content, no e-mail should be sent.
} 
else 
{
    # third condition and the default condition if it does not match the other conditions
    $emailOptions.Subject     = "Active Directory Accounts To Check"
    $emailOptions.Attachments = $fileToCheck.FullName
    Send-MailMessage @emailOptions
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried to run and get the following : term elseif and else is not recognized . working on it

Comment: Sorry, I misplaced the comments. See updated example

Comment: The syntax is correct, did you test a 1-on-1 copy or did you change something? I corrected the Attachment parameter

Comment: OK, thanks now getting that filetoCheck is not recognized : $fileToCheck = Get-Item -Path (Join-Path $folder test.zip) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Comment: Get-Item -Path (Join-Path $folder\test.zip) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue     -- missing a \ ,  now i get a prompt: childpath

Comment: all fixed. Thanks mhu for your help once again

Comment: for Second condition : Is it possible to add an alert for that - if the zip file is empty- or does not have all the files (incomplete) send an email

Comment: Just set an appropriate Subject and send the mail from the second condition block

Comment: 1st and 3rd condition are working fine.  2nd condition : if zip file is incomplete or empty - sends an alert - progress

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194838/discussion-between-user-9191-and-mhu).