# Zip-File is incomplete or empty- Powershell

Tags: powershell

Working with the following Script : [email to check size / if it's complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562094/email-to-check-size-if-its-complete/56562893?noredirect=1#comment99710471_56562893)
 goal : Check if the zip file is empty or incomplete and then then sends an email

Folder A has 2 subfolders: B and C. Zip file is inside of folder A, it grabs all files from A -B -C and zip them. If its incomplete or some odd reason zip file is empty, send an email "ALERT:

```
elseif ($fileToCheck -and ($fileToCheck.Length -le 2)) 
# ((($fileToCheck) -and-(Get-ChildItem $fileToCheck | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0))
{
 # second condition: If the file exists and was created today, but has no content or incomplete, e-mail should be sent.

$emailOptions.Subject = "test.zip is empty or Incomplete"
$emailOptions.Attachments = $fileToCheck.FullName
Send-MailMessage @emailOptions
 }
```

Problem : Script runs on powershell but I do not receive any emails

Comment: Is there a question? What about this is not working for you? etc.....

Comment: @postanote its not working, the scripts runs  but does not give any errors and I do not receive any emails